# Conjugation on subgroups of $A_4$ faithful?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $X$ be the set of all subgroups of $G=A_4$. We define the group action $$G\times X\ni(g,H)\mapsto gHg^{-1}\in X$$
I am trying to determine whether this action is faithful, i.e. $\bigcap_{H\in X} Stab(H)=\{e\}$.

The subgroup $\langle(123)\rangle$ has stabiliser $\langle(123)\rangle$ and  $\langle(124)\rangle$ has stabiliser $\langle(124)\rangle$. From $$\bigcap_{H\in X} Stab(H)\subseteq \langle(123)\rangle\cap \langle(124)\rangle = \{e\}$$
I deduce that the group action is faithful.

Does this look okay?

Comment: But $(23)\notin A_4$, I think.

Comment: Oops! I read $S_4$ for some reason. Then your solution looks good to me!

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* way is to take an $H\in X$ for which the stabilizer is trivial, for example $\{(123),(234)\}$.  But your proof is also true, so of course it works just as well.

Comment: I don't think $A_4$ has a subgroup which has a trivial stabiliser (under conjugation). And besides, I don't think $\{(123),(234)\}$ is a subgroup of $A_4$.

Comment: @Thomas So what? $X$ is the set of all subsets, not the set of all subgroups.

Comment: Oh dear, I meant "let $X$ be the set of all subgroups". Sorry about that.